# UPS stacking in a small room

Tags: ups

I want to know if it is good/standard to put UPS on top of another UPS. It sounds crazy but we don't have enough space in our room. So what would be the consequences that I might face if I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What type of UPS ? With proper cooling, you can do that, but in a room without controlled temperature the battery of the stacked UPSes may overheat.

If you have to position them in such way due to space limitations you should make sure there's enough space between them to allow enough air for cooling purposes.

So put them on top of each other if you must, but leave some space for airflow.